# How to listen to the input event of the Stripe cardElement to determine if card is invalid and disable the button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, stripe-payments

As my user fills out the form with order info and customer details, I have the submit button disabled until my validations are satisfied. The library I'm using is express-validate.

What I want to do *also*, is keep the button disabled, ***first***  until the user inputs the credit card info into the Stripe element and it is in fact a valid card. ***Secondly***, upon submit, disable the button again so the user can't keep clicking the button. When the success or success or error notification comes back I'll redirect.

As of now I am not successful in getting the cardElement.on() method to trigger, [Stripe events](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events). And this was the example of what I am trying to achieve,[see client.js](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder)

This is what I have so far...

Home.vue

```
<form
    id="order-info"
    class="form-container"
    @submit.prevent="createOrder"
  >
  ...

<div class="stripe-container">
        <div id="stripe-element-card" ref="card">
          <!-- Stripe.js injects the Card Element -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <p id="card-error" role="alert" />
      <p class="result-message hidden">
        Payment succeeded
      </p>
      <button
        v-if="toggleUserInfo"
        id="submit"
        class="stripe"
        :disabled="$v.$invalid" // this is based on current form validations
        type="submit"
        // I want to disable also until card is valid and then disable again 
        // after user clicks to prevent additional clicking until success/error returns
      >
        <div
          id="spinner"
          class="spinner"
          :class="{ hidden: !isLoading }"
        ></div>
        <span id="button-text" :class="{ hidden: isLoading }">Pay now</span>


<script>
async mounted() {
stripe = await loadStripe(process.env.VUE_APP_STRIPE_PK);
elements = stripe.elements();
card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
card.mount("#stripe-element-card");
 },

...
```

createOrder method

```
async createOrder(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  this.loading(true);
  this.$v.$touch();
  if (!this.$v.$invalid) {

    // gather order and user details, superfluous code

    const cardElement = elements.getElement("card");

    const billingDetails = {
      name: user.name,
      address: {
        city: user.city,
        line1: user.street,
        state: "NY"
      },
      phone: user.phone
    };
    try {
      cardElement.on("change", event => {
        console.log("LOGGING THE CARD ELEMENT EVENT", event);
        // NOT SEEING ANYTHING HERE
        // disable button until valid card is inputted
      });
      ...
```

EDIT

When implementing Pompey's answer below, the listener in mounted(), this is what the console.logs look like until the credit card input is complete...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important thing to note is that your `change` handler that wants to enable the button that triggers `createOrder` is located in the `createOrder` method itself. I would move the handler code to just after the card element is mounted in Home.vue:

```
card.mount("#stripe-element-card");
cardElement.on("change", event => {
  console.log("LOGGING THE CARD ELEMENT EVENT", event);
  if (event.complete) {
    // enable payment button
  } else if (event.error) {
    // show event.error.message to customer
  }
});
```

And as you can see from my snippet above, the `event`  parameter has a `complete` property that is set to `true` when the card element’s value is “well-formed and potentially complete”[1] so when it is true you can enable your button. It can also be worth checking the `event.error` in your `change` handler and if one is present, showing the user the `event.error.message`.

Similarly, to redirect the customer or re-enable the button based on the payment’s success, you can use the `then` method to get the response from `confirmCardPayment` indicating success or failure[2]:

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    ...
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    if(result.error)
    {
      // Display result.error.message and re-enable button to allow for more attempts
    }
    else
    {
      // React to successful payment
    }
  });
```

[1]https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=cardElement#element_on_change-handler-complete

[2]https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment

Comment: Excellent! Mounted() was in fact the place to listen to the event.complete property. My only remaining question is why the listener had to be attached when the DOM node, button, is initially being mounted? Is that because all listeners need to be registered on the window object before the document is loaded.